# Объясните структуру ошибок в android?

Tags: java, android

Недавно начал изучать android/java и столкнулся с тем, что текст ошибок не объясняет причины ее возникновения. Единственным путем понять, что не так на данный момент является гугл-запрос с точным текстом ошибки. Но хочется разобраться в самой структуре построения сообщения об ошибке.

Вот пример ошибки из Android Studio:

> Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.langRuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/android/jdk1.8.0.91/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>
> BUILD FAILED

все что я понял из этого сообщения, что некая функция вернула "1" и изза этого случился BUILD FAILED

при этом перейти на место в коде где это случилось не получается, и остается единственный способ искать в гугле решение похожей проблемы

Гуру, объясните как самому найти и решить проблему вызывающую ошибку?

Спасибо.

P.S.
стаж в IT больше 10 лет, но эти сообщения вводят в недоумение

может я не там смотрю, но других ошибок не вижу

добавил логи

`Event Log`:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources,     :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:assembleDebug]
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72221Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42221Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
:app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:buildInfoDebugLoader
:app:transformClassesWithExtractJarsForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
:app:transformResourcesAndNative_libsWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug
:app:transformClasses_enhancedWithInstant+reloadDexForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugTasks
:app:prePackageMarkerForDebug
:app:fastDeployDebugExtractor
:app:generateDebugInstantRunAppInfo
:app:coldswapKickerDebug
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunSlicerForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/android/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.656 secs
```

Messages Grade Build:

```
>Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:assembleDebug]
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72221Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42221Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
:app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:buildInfoDebugLoader
:app:transformClassesWithExtractJarsForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
:app:transformResourcesAndNative_libsWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug
:app:transformClasses_enhancedWithInstant+reloadDexForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugTasks
:app:prePackageMarkerForDebug
:app:fastDeployDebugExtractor
:app:generateDebugInstantRunAppInfo
:app:coldswapKickerDebug
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunSlicerForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/android/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 1.656 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: на самом деле это значит что сборщик вернул код 1 (не 0). Т.е. произошла ошибка на этапе сборки. А что именно нужно смотреть в сообщения об ошибке в самый верх.

Comment: смотрю в окне `Messages Gradle Build`, единственная ошибка `:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED`, других ошибок нет, может я не там смотрю?

Comment: там выше где-то должо быть описание ошибки. Намного выше в логе.

Comment: может я не там смотрю?
добавил логи в главное сообщение (в коммент не влезает)

Comment: Проверьте библиотеки, это может из за них. Добавьте используемые и удалите не нужные. Потом Rebuild.

Comment: @Saidolim , у меня обычный `hello world` , ребилд делал много раз, не помогает. Собственно хотелось понять в чем ошибка, а ребилд сродни хлопанья дверями и стуку по колесам

Comment: Так там явно написано: "* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output." Выполните с этими аргументами и посмотрите более детальный лог

Answer (score 2):

Это вообще-то ошибка сборщика `Gradle`, а конкретнее, ошибка трансформации `class`-файлов в `dex` байткод.
Еще конкретнее можно сказать, взглянув на ваш `build.gradle`.
Скорее всего, вы пытаетесь подключить какую-то библиотеку, байткод которой несовместим с `Android`.

Comment: Огромное человеческое спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

В аналогичной ситуации помогло пересборкой проекта - **Rebuild Project**.

1. Очистка проекта (Build/Clean Project)
2. Сборка проекта (Build/Rebuild Project)
3. Стартуем на устройстве

Comment: Опишите решение проблемы более детально. Сейчас ваш ответ выглядит, как комментарий.